# IE seems to uncheck an indeterminate checkbox whereas Chrome and FF will check it on click

Tags: javascript, css, internet-explorer, checkbox, kendo-ui

IE seems to uncheck an indeterminate checkbox on click whereas Chrome and FF will check it on click.
Can any one confirm this behavior and perhaps suggest a way to make the behavior uniform across all browsers?

This is IE8,9,10 and all versions of chrome and FF less than a year old.

```
fake code so I can submit jsFiddle link, that's weird....
```

Head over to this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JEDBG/) for an example.

Check **about.html** and **index.html** then **Kendo UI Project**

Notice how IE yields a different result.

Comment: Any chance you could post a jsfiddle or something similar?

Comment: What does the HTML look like? And why is this tagged javascript? Are you using javascript?

Comment: Working on adding some HTML -- yes the click event is intercepted and read in JS in order to decide what to do.

Comment: IE10 and Chrome do the same for me.

Comment: The state that's printed when you click on the last node is true in both instances?

Comment: In all my browsers: `indeterminate + click => checked`. You could override all toggles with `preventDefault()` and manually set `.checked` and `.indeterminate`, but I guarantee it's not worth it. Use the browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are using jQuery in your fiddle, I've removed the `onclick` handlers from the `inputs`, and targeted them directly from the JavaScript. Live Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JEDBG/1/

```
$('body').on('click', 'input', function () {
    $('#result').html('<br/>state: ' + this.checked);
});
```

IE now produces the expected result.

p.s. Don't be alarmed by the difference in our fiddles. I have just included the external resources the way jsfiddle prefers and moved the different code languages into their respective panels.